# How to calculate the $i$-th element in the sequence of prime numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

The sequence of prime numbers is the set of prime numbers in their natural order (that is, $2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17,...$). The German wikipedia entry on sequences [states the following](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folge_(Mathematik)#Angabe_.C3.BCber_einen_Algorithmus):

> Given $i$, there is no other way to name the $i$-th prime number than to
>   calculate the whole sequence of prime numbers from the first to the $(i-1)$-th element.

Is this provably true and if so, how can it be proven?

Comment: As far as I know, this is not provably true. The problem is rather that there is no known formula (up to now), which allows us to compute the $i$-th prime in an efficient way. See e.g. here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes.

Comment: I believe that if a formula exists, it's probably so complicated you're better off just sieving up to $i$.

Comment: you in fact don't need sieving up to i. You need sieving from (i-1) and up.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't seem like it can be true, as we have implementations that are much faster than generating primes.  See the answers to this question:  [Most efficient algorithm for nth prime, deterministic and probabilistic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507178/most-efficient-algorithm-for-nth-prime-deterministic-and-probabilistic).

Simplistically, you use an n-th prime approximation to get you very close, run a fast prime count algorithm to give you the exact answer at the approximation, then sieve and count the difference.

Edit: To relate to the wikipedia entry, not only *do* we have another way, but it is a much faster way.  The statement is false.  We don't have a [useful](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/953751/117584) explicit formula, which is probably more what the author meant to convey.