# What is the run time for the most efficient algorithms for $p_n$ and $pi(n)$

Tags: algorithms, prime-numbers, computer-science, computational-complexity

Really a 2 part question: What is the fastest way to find the nth prime and the inverse function $pi(n)$? And secondly what is the run-time of the algorithms?

Comment: A question similar to your first question was already asked on this site. [Most efficient algorithm for nth prime, deterministic and probabilistic?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507178/most-efficient-algorithm-for-nth-prime-deterministic-and-probabilistic). And this [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/507206) seems to give information on your second question.

Comment: You could also use [The nth Prime Page](https://primes.utm.edu/nthprime/)